# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy._lib'

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, scipy

I read two or three questions related to this problem but I haven't found any solution yet. I don't understand why I have this error.

I am using `Python 3.7` and installed `scipy`using the `pip` installer and it worked properly. For those who want to know, I was testing this [program](https://pastebin.com/npiNdNTM) (from [this website](https://apmonitor.com/pdc/index.php/Main/SolveDifferentialEquations)).

If I go in my Python libraries I have two folders as shown on the image below
[image: \Lib\site_packages]

Now if I go to the `scipy` folder, I actually have a `_lib` folder as shown in the image below. So I don't really understand why this error raised up. And I don't know nor understand what I should do. 
[image: \scipy_lib]

I don't have any file called `integrate` inside this folder, so either I am wrong about where to find the module or I have an obsolete `scipy version` which seems to be hard to know if you just use the `pip` installer.

The full error code is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\YANN\Desktop\Numerical Method - Python\odeint_example.py", line 2, in <module>
    from scipy.integrate import odeint
  File "C:\Users\YANN\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\scipy\__init__.py", line 110, in <module>
    from scipy._lib._version import NumpyVersion as _NumpyVersion
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scipy._lib'
```

Also in the file `scipy._lib._version.py` the docstring of the `NumpyVersion` class is shown after and I am wondering if it's ok to have a `numpy version 1.15.2`? I like my 1.15.2 numpy version...

```
class NumpyVersion():
    """Parse and compare numpy version strings.

Numpy has the following versioning scheme (numbers given are examples; they
can be >9) in principle):

- Released version: '1.8.0', '1.8.1', etc.
- Alpha: '1.8.0a1', '1.8.0a2', etc.
- Beta: '1.8.0b1', '1.8.0b2', etc.
- Release candidates: '1.8.0rc1', '1.8.0rc2', etc.
- Development versions: '1.8.0.dev-f1234afa' (git commit hash appended)
- Development versions after a1: '1.8.0a1.dev-f1234afa',
                                 '1.8.0b2.dev-f1234afa',
                                 '1.8.1rc1.dev-f1234afa', etc.
- Development versions (no git hash available): '1.8.0.dev-Unknown'

Comparing needs to be done against a valid version string or other
`NumpyVersion` instance.

Parameters
----------
vstring : str
    Numpy version string (``np.__version__``).

Notes
-----
All dev versions of the same (pre-)release compare equal.

Examples
--------
>>> from scipy._lib._version import NumpyVersion
>>> if NumpyVersion(np.__version__) < '1.7.0':
...     print('skip')
skip

>>> NumpyVersion('1.7')  # raises ValueError, add ".0"

"""
```

Any tips will be very appreciated! :)

Comment: Oops, I haven't seen I had to go in the Roaming folder (why not...) then I copy pasted the folder in my current path into the Roaming Python etc. and it works!  I will leave the question here in case of someone as the same problem. Sorry for the inconvenience.